# Jquery ui .sortable() enable-disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

First of all, let me explain my page structure, so you can get the idea how is it working. I've got some number of `quick-button` blocks. 
They can be sorted by Jquery ui `.sortable()` method, but only after pressing `settings` button (which allows quick buttons to be sortable). Later, order of this buttons could be saved or could be canceled. 
So I need to look through 3 conditions which are fired up by `click` event. 
Problem is, on first time everything is ok, but on second time when I'm trying to press button `settings`  - `sortable()` method is not working anymore.

You can see my JS below:

```
    $('#tune-hot-links').click(function () { //Click "settings" button  
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable();
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").disableSelection();      
    });
    $('.button-editgroup button.button-save').click(function () {   //Click "save" button       
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable('disabled');
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").enableSelection();               
    });
    $('.button-editgroup button.button-cancel').click(function () { //Click "cancel" button 
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable('cancel');
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable('disabled');
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").enableSelection();   
    });
```

I've already tried to change `.sortable()` to `.sortable('enable')` at `#tune-hot-links` event. And it's not working.

Comment: can you post a fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have no idea why, but seems that changing code like this:

```
$('#tune-hot-links').on( "click", function() {      
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable("enable");          
    });
    $('.button-editgroup button.button-save').on( "click", function() {         
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable("disable");
    });

    $('.button-editgroup button.button-cancel').on( "click", function() {   
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable('cancel');
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").sortable("disable");
            $(".sect-hot-links-inner").enableSelection();   
    });
```

Resolved that issue.